# Python Tkinter setting an inactive border to a text box?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, border

Is it possible to get a text box to have a border even when inactive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure I know what "border when inactive" means, but you can certainly add a border to a Text in TkInter. The following code creates two outer frames and two inner frames, then adds a Text to each inner frame. The frames are given a border of 5 px on all sides.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

left_outer = Frame(root, bd=1)
left_outer.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, pady=5, padx=5)
right_outer = Frame(root, bd=1)
right_outer.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, pady=5, padx=5)

left = Frame(left_outer, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
right = Frame(right_outer, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
left.pack(fill=Y)
right.pack(fill=Y)

t_start = Text(left, width=20, height=200)
t_start.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
s_start = Scrollbar(left)
s_start.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
s_start.config(command=t_start.yview)
t_start.config(yscrollcommand=s_start.set)

t_end = Text(right, width=20, height=200)
t_end.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
s_end = Scrollbar(right)
s_end.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
s_end.config(command=t_end.yview)
t_end.config(yscrollcommand=s_end.set)

root.geometry("400x200")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

odie5533's answer covers giving a border to a frame that contains only a Text object. This is a great way to give a 2D around a text object, but adds another widget in the mix. I think the original question was related to setting both the border width and relief type of the Text object. This snippet gives a relief to the Text object without involving another frame.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text_top = Text(root, relief=GROOVE, height=5, width = 40, borderwidth=2)
text_top.pack()

text_bottom = Text(root, relief=RIDGE, height=5, width = 40, borderwidth=2)
text_bottom.pack()

root.geometry("400x200")
root.mainloop()
```